# Cat refuses to walk on carpet?

Tags: cats, behavior, vocalizations

A few days ago, our cat has started to avoid walking on the carpet. Our living room is carpeted and has been the whole time we have been in the property and had the cat. As of a few days ago he had no issues with the carpet. He’d wonder round the carpet constantly, sleep on the carpet, eat treats on the carpet.

All of a sudden he has become scared of the carpet in the room? He refuses to walk on the carpet. He actively avoids the carpet using other obstacles (table, sofa, window ledge, etc) to get across the room. When left in the room he is becoming more vocal and we don’t know what to do?

He doesn’t seem to have any issues with any of the other rooms in the house. (Carpet is the same)

If anyone has any idea as to what my have caused this or what we can do to get him back to his normal self?

One of the neighbourhood cats came in the window the other day, is that a possibility of the cause? Although he started to be skittish before the cat had come in.

Any ideas or solutions would be really helpful as we don’t know what to do.

Comment: What's the state of his claws? I noticed that whenever the claws of my cat grow too long she snags fibers of the carpet with each step or even gets one claw tangled on rare occasions. Especially the outer claws (pinky and thumb) cause her problems. This could cause a cat enough discomfort to avoid certain carpets.

Comment: Becoming more vocal: I've concluded that some cats just like echoes, or are delivering soliloquies no human will ever understand. The yowls certainly don't seem to be addressed to me, unlike meows. Could be she's lonely; we lost her brother about five years ago... but I don't know how to ask her if she'd tolerate  another cat in the house except by trying it, and I haven't been willing to inflict the possible disagreement upon another cat. So far.